# If the Current Date falls into last 3 business days of the month, Desired Date 'month' should change to ‘Next month’

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can you guys help me achieve the below logic in SQL Server (T-SQL)

If the Current Date falls into last 3 business days of the month, Desired Date 'month' should change to ‘Next month’

Example:

```
20180627 (Current Date) --> 201807 (Desired Date),

20180529 --> 201806,
20190226 --> 201903,
20181227 --> 201901
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: "business date" is quite a requirement. Do you have a table that has date,business_flag fields? Or any other means (function etc) to determine if a date is a business one?

Comment: What is a business date? Monday-Friday? What about if it's a public holiday? Do you have a calendar table?

Comment: Also `'201806'`,`'201807'`,`'201903'` and `'201901'` aren't dates. Do you want  the `date` `20180601` returned, or the `varchar` `'201806'` returned?

Comment: Without a calendar table you are fighting an impossible fight here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/

Comment: You can solve it by building a very complex expression only god will understand, or creating a calendar table.

Comment: Just noticed you've tagged `sql-server-2008` and `sql-server-2012`. Which is correct? Please remove the incorrect tag. Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Comment: Business days are from Monday-Friday. Public Holidays can be ignored.

Comment: @Rob Famous last words. At some point, this won't be true - holidays are not the only "non-work" day - ask the people currently living through a volcanic eruption. If you're lucky, you won't be supporting this system/code when this happens, but yourself and everyone that follows you a huge favor and implement a calendar table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `eomonth()`:

```
select (case when getdate() >= cast(dateadd(day, -2, eomonth(getdate())) as date)
             then year(dateadd(month, 1, getdate())) * 100 + month(dateadd(month, 1, getdate()))
             else year(getdate()) * 100 + month(getdate())
        end) as desired_month
```

Comment: Syntax is quite wrong in that, Gordon. `DATEADD`'s 1st parameter is the time period, and the second is the value, for example `DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())`; you have it the wrong way round. Also, if you use a date like `'20180628'` you get `201806`, however, I'm pretty sure the OP would want `'201807'` (owing to `20180630` being a Saturday).

Comment: I just gave `20180627` a go, and that comes back as `'201806'`. According to the OP's question, it should be `'201807'`. If you try ``20180628`` you'll also get the same (wrong) result.

Comment: Looks like EOMONTH works only on 2012. Sorry for the incorrect tag. 2008 SQL Server is what I have.